# Integrate MS botframework in android app

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, botframework, chatbot

I have created a basic Q&A bot using the MS bot framework. Now I want to integrate this chatbot in an android app as a feature. Can you tell me how do i do this.
Point me in the right direction.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create chat board then use [**API.AI(API.AI is now Dialogflow)**](https://dialogflow.com/) provided by Google

Building engaging voice and text-based conversational interfaces powered by AI.

Comment: I have created chat board by using API.AI, but right now i m not able to give my code you can search it and u get many tutorials

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve your requirement.

- You can try to [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) in android to embed your bot application's endpoint. Which I think is the simplest method. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-design-pattern-embed-app for the similar scenario. Also which will leverage the repo https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat, you can refer this for more info.
- You can try to implement Direct Line in Android. You can refer to the unofficial repo https://github.com/brijrajsingh/DirectLineAndroidSample for hint.

Hope it helps.